# In what sort of department can I pursue a PhD in fan behaviour?

Tags: phd, economics, social-media, psychology, anthropology

I'm planning to do PhD on the Fan culture to be specific - A comparative study on the effects of Digital media on Football Fan behaviour on supporters of European football clubs in Indonesia and India. The core basis for comparison is the origins of fan culture in India and Indonesia, where for India it was non-existent and for Indonesia it was already robust before TV arrived.

I want it to be a statistical analysis on a large sample data collected over questionnaires (internet) identifying variables which drive incentives psychologically and economically and also want to include focus group interviews. The point of origin of research is the influence of the introduction of Cable TV and the Internet.

However, I'm really confused as to which subject department I should apply to, am most likely to get funding in and would be the best fit for such a topic. Fan behaviour has crossovers from psychology, economics, sociology, anthropology and Media.

I have a masters in Economics and have 6 years of experience working in Analytics mostly in statistical modelling for FCMG Brands. Following which I spent the next 4 years trying to document football in Asian.

Comment: Are you aware of who is doing this kind of research currently? If you use Google Scholar and can find who is publishing and what institutions or departments they are part of, that'll give you a good idea. Additionally, at least in the USA, the funding tends to dictate what you work on. One way to ensure you work on this is to apply to the institutions that are involved in this research.

Comment: What do you want to do after your PhD?  What sort of PhD to people who do those things now have?  That should guide your choice of department.

Comment: Perhaps https://fanmakers.com/ might advisee.

Comment: The project you describe (questionnaire + focus group) seems to me to fall under sociology, but really, you know better. See kjacks21's comment; I assume you have read quite a few papers on the subject while working on that proposal (right?).